How to run and debug file .so (linux library) in IDA PRO or another debugger?
For reverse engineering purposes, i need to run file lib.so under debbuging, in this case IDA PRO wont debug dynamic libraries like that, so i am searching for decision how to debug this file or call functions from it and debug them.
In IDA PRO view of lib, there are three main functions named: start( is entrypoint), bind and .init_proc.
Because of IDA tells that dynamic library cannot run by it self, i tried to compile program that initiates start of call function that need to debug from lib.so (with connection this lib in my program using gcc) or trying to call and debug functions from lib directly.
But all my attempts was unsuccessful, because GCC tell that it could not compile program or  function that i need to run and debug is exported, but not picked up by the library, or in IDA PRO Modules section of lib.so, tells "no string table".
More information about .so and what im trying to reverse here:
https://blog.netlab.360.com/ssh_stealer_facefish_en/
here is code that i tried to use to solve my problem
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define FUNC_NAME "printf"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* libc_handle = dlopen("/tmp/libs.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (libc_handle == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open libs.so: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    void* start_func = dlsym(libc_handle, FUNC_NAME);
    if (start_func == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find start function: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(libc_handle);
        return 1;
    }

    void (*start)() = (void (*)()) start_func;
    start();

    dlclose(libc_handle);

    return 0;
}

and another one
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *start();
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("func called ok!\n");
    start();
    return 0;
}


You won't debug libc this way. Luckily, both glibc and musl are open source. (Though it isn't an easy read, not suitable for beginners.)
